# Inserting data from html to php to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

I have done my research but have found nothing specific enough to my problem
I have an HTML form, asking for data, then a php script that is suppose to put the data in a mysql database

When i try it on my localhost, i dont get any errors
but when i check on phpmyadmin, there is no new data

the html:

```
<html>
<head>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
ID: <input type="text" name="ID"><br>
Family ID: <input type="text" name="Family_ID"><br>
First Name: <input type="text" name="First_Name"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="Last_Name"><br>
Gender: <input type="text" name="Gender"><br>
Birthday: <input type="text" name="Birthday"><br>
Birthplace: <input type="text" name="Birthplace"><br>
Father ID: <input type="text" name="Father_ID"><br>
Mother ID: <input type="text" name="Mother_ID"><br>
Maiden Name: <input type="text" name="Maiden_Name"><br>
Mariage ID: <input type="text" name="Mariage_ID"><br>
Deathdate: <input type="text" name="Deathdate"><br>
Deathplace: <input type="text" name="Deathplace"><br>
Grave Location: <input type="text" name="Grave_Location"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="Email"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="Phone"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="Adress"><br>
Bio: <input type="text" name="Bio"><br>
Studies: <input type="text" name="Travail"><br>
Travail: <input type="text" name="Travail"><br>
Photo: <input type="text" name="Photo"><br>
Fete: <input type="text" name="Fete"><br>
<input type="Submit">

</form>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the php:

```
$username='root';
$password='121395';
$database='genealogy';
mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( 'Unable to select database');
echo "Connected to MySQL";

$ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);
$Family_ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Family_ID']);
$First_Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First_Name']);
$Last_Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Last_Name']);
$Gender=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Gender']);
$Birthday=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Birthday']);
$Birthplace=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Birthplace']);
$Father_ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Father_ID']);
$Mother_ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mother_ID']);
$Maiden_Name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Maiden_Name']);
$Mariage_ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Mariage_ID']);
$Deathdate=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Deathdate']);
$Deathplace=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Deathplace']);
$Grave_Location=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Grave_Location']);
$Email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
$Phone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Phone']);
$Address=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Adress']);
$Bio=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Bio']);
$Travail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Travail']);
$Photo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Photo']);
$Fete=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Fete']);


$query = "INSERT INTO bouan (ID, Family_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Gender, Birthday, 
Birthplace, Father_ID, Mother_ID, Maiden_Name, Mariage_ID,Deathdate, Deatchplace,
Grave_Location, Email, Phone, Adress, Bio, Travail, Photo, Fete) VALUES 
('$ID','$Family_ID','$First_Name','$Last_Name','$Gender','$Birthday','$Birthplace',
'$Father_ID','$Mother_ID','$Maiden_Name','$Mariage_ID','$Deathdate','$Deathplace',
'$Grave_Location','$Email','$Phone','$Address','$Bio','$Travail','$Photo','$Fete')";

mysql_query($query) or die ("Error updating database");

mysql_error();
mysql_close();
```

All i get in return is:

Connected to MySQLError updating database

whats wrong? (i HAVE done my research, over 2 days fyi)
im sorry that im new to this, cant help it

Comment: There is so much wrong and insecure about this code I beg you take it offline immediately and run through some "saving to mysql" tutorials, as well some basic PHP/MySQL security reading.

Comment: Not to forget that there are arrays in PHP for a reason, they can make your life easier. Less code = less bugs.

Comment: The quality of your post is rather low because you haven't done your research before posting here. As suggested you should read some tutorial first. Good luck!

Comment: this isn't online yet, i know about the security risks,
i am just trying to learn the basics, after 2 days of trying to figure out whats wrong i finally decided to post here
thanks for links, 
i wasn't expecting such a harsh welcoming...

Comment: btw i did this following a tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach looks fine, but for security reasons fetch the posted variables like below `$ID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ID']);`
mysql_real_escape_string() method will remove the unwanted characters and makes it secure.

At the end try to print the query which you are executing using echo or print statement.

```
echo $query;
```

Execute the result on your phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin will let you know what are the errors in your mysql query and following those instructions you can change your query.

Debugging can be done by printing the results after each line execution wherever you feel something is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for your straightforward response, and not yelling at me because im a begginer

Comment: Why should i yell at you? we have this community to help each other. Even I am a learner like you. You can ask any kind of question, but a good description about the problem will help you to get better solution. Enjoy... :)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably

- provide `mysql_query` with the real query
- sanitize data before feeding it to sql
- use `{$_POST['whatever']}` when you want to embed it into a string
- check the return value of `mysql_query`
- learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_error()` to receive last error. Also I see potential bug in your query:

```
'`$ID`','`$Family_ID`','`$First_Name`' -- you may try to remove ` sign
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do these 2 things, first add value attribute to your all input elements
e.g)

```
<input type="text" name="Family_ID" value="">
```

because it will not get into $_POST variable if you send blank value in the text box with no value attribute

try to add filed names so that you can track map with values and remove 
    `
 from your field and value.